Why would Recoil cause hydration errors, even when atoms are not stored in localStorage?
I have an atom that retrieves a token from cookies and determines whether the user has authority or not to perform a certain action (such as edit and add). Now, I understand that when atoms are stored in localStorage, it can cause hydration errors.
However, the atoms that I am using are NOT stored in localStorage and the HTML is valid. I have also confirmed that it is actually Recoil causing the problem (hydration errors disappeared when element rendered conditionally by an atom was removed).
For example, (hydration error)
const isUserAuthorized = useRecoilValue(operatorAuthorizationState(UserRolesEnum.STAFF))

return(
   <div>
      {isUserAuthorized ? 'authorized' : 'not authorized'}
   </div
)

(no hydration error)
const isUserAuthorized = useRecoilValue(operatorAuthorizationState(UserRolesEnum.STAFF))

return(
   <div>
      // {isUserAuthorized ? 'authorized' : 'not authorized'}
   </div
)

Why would Recoil cause hydration errors, even when atoms are not stored in localStorage?
I have tried disabling SSR for the whole application, which removes the hydration errors. However, since it is bad practice I would like another way to solve this problem.
I have also tried creating a state with the useState hook, then setting it to true when the component mounts, checking if it is truthy then using the atom. However, I do not want to do this every time I use Recoil.
For example:
const [componentRendered, setComponentRendered] = useState(false)
const isUserAuthorized = useRecoilValue(operatorAuthorizationState(UserRolesEnum.STAFF))

useEffect(()=>{
   setComponentRendered(true)
},[])

return(
   <div>
       {componentRendered && isUserAuthorized ? 'authorized' : 'not authorized'}
   </div
)

return
